# Recover database (SQL Server) from Windows.old folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, sql-server

I have just installed Windows 7 on a machine which previously ran Windows XP. The old installation had a database which I need a copy of, but of course I did not think far enough ahead to do a backup before I installed the new OS.

So, the question is, is it possible to recover the old database without having a backup file? I tried to copy the files from the Data folder, but this did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version and edition of SQL server?  Did you try to `attach` the database, or did you just copy the files and hope the server would see them?

I've only ever seen this happen with a machine that was running MSDE.  When the W7 upgrade ran, it did not shut MSDE down gracefully, nor did it disconnect it cleanly*.  The really short version of a painfully long story: we had to roll the machine back to the last image that the client had of it with XP, then do it the right way.  I had no luck salvaging the original MDF.

Please provide more information on your version of SQL and what, exactly, you've tried, and I'll try to provide more help.

---

*(The MDF file was left in a read-only state, and possibly corrupted.  SQL 2k5 won't attach an MDF that's read-only; reinstalling MSDE and attempting to reattach also didn't work (the possible corruption).

Comment: Turned out not to be an issue since the application created new tables as long as it had a DB with the right name. But thanx anyway. Good knowledge to bring with me.